# validate form using jquery validation before submitting through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I am trying to submit a form using Ajax to a certain page and then get the message back. I am trying to validate the form using jqueryvalidation plug-in.
I am using following code for submitting the form through Ajax.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#footercontact").submit(function(event) {
    form = $('#footercontact').serialize();
    $('#footercontact').validate();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/test',
      data: form,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        $("#contactname").val('Name');
        $("#contactemail").val('Email');
        $("#contactmessage").val('Message');
        $("#contactsuccess").html(data);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});

</script>
```

Currently this code is directly posting the code without any validation.If there is any thing another you need to know please ask me. And if you know any other method for validating the form before submitting it through Ajax then please Help.
here is html code of form

```
<form name="footercontact" id="footercontact" method="POST" action="">

  <input type="text" id="contactname" name="name" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name')this.value='';" value="Name" class="required">

  <input type="text" id="contactemail" name="email" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email')this.value='';" value="Email" class="required email">

  <textarea name="message" id="contactmessage" cols="" rows="" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Message';" onfocus="if (this.value=='Message')this.value='';" value="Message" class="required"></textarea>

  <input name="submit" type="button" onclick="jsvalidate()" value="Submit" id="submitsave">

</form>
```

Comment: Where did you define your validation rules?

Comment: actually I am using jquery validation plugin that validates the form.  you can read about it here: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/  this is working only when i am not using Ajax. but using it with the code above it just posts the data .

Comment: Did you read the doc of it? Did you define your validation rules? (either in markup or in validate method?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('#footercontact').valid()` which `return boolean`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#footercontact").submit(function(event) {
    form = $(this).serialize();
    $(this).validate();
    if (!$(this).valid()) return false;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/test',
      data: form,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        $("#contactname").val('Name');
        $("#contactemail").val('Email');
        $("#contactmessage").val('Message');
        $("#contactsuccess").html(data);
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();

  });
});
```